# We are sorry a server error occurred. Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, server-error

I have been getting a weird error (We are sorry a server error occurred, please try again later) when trying to get folder with DriveApp. Below is the code. Anyone else encountering the same problem and has found a fix?

```
function test() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(APPROVAL_FOLDER_ID);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you sure the Id is valid?

Comment: I'm getting this error from time to time. Looks more like a temporary error on Google-side to me. Did you manage to reproduce it?

Comment: It comes out for me everytime, I found a fix for it tho. Add Drive API from slack and that fixed it for me since I am creating a slackbot.

Comment: I'm experiencing this error with an RSS feed generator. I have identical script: one is with this problem and one has not. If I do a copy of the spreadsheet with the working script, the new copied one does not work.

Comment: I found the solution. Add Drive API from Cloud Platform fixes it.